# Designing FIR filters

Tags: digital-logic, embedded, filter

How can we realize a second order digital FIR filter without using a microcontroller. What assumptions would be taken?

Comment: Why can't it use a microcontroller or DSP?  What are your filter requirement, like bandwidth, shape of the passband, noise, etc?

Comment: What *can* you use?

Comment: Second order does only mean 2 (or is it 3?) data points. You could do it with discrete at that level, it would be useless, but you could easily, you could actually easily implement with a few op amps and sample and hold circuits.

Comment: Some ceramic filters are in fact FIR filters. Simply visualised, the electrodes are layed out like a comb on a piezo electric crystal. The length of the teeth can be compared with the weight of a FIR filter taps. http://bg-electronics.de/catalog/images/G1968M.jpg

Comment: @jippie: You're thinking of certain types of SAW (surface acoustic wave) filters. However, the question does specify *digital* FIR filter.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes! I forgot the name of them. They're brilliant little devices when it comes to filtering.

Answer (score 2):

A DSP would be ideal, it has special instructions like MAC (Multiply and Accumulate) for this. But it still is a kind of microcontroller.

If you don't want to use a microcontroller or DSP the only option is programmable logic, FPGA or CPLD. Doing it with more discrete logic is way too complex: you need a FIFO for your samples and one for the coefficients, and a multiplier to compute the product of sample x coefficient, and add all the products.

If you have many terms and/or a high sample rate I would go the FPGA path or DSP, otherwise microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Digital filters such as FIR or IIR can be implemented with logic chips... no matter what you will need to have an ADC which I guess you can build by using op-amps